# rails update question: where are the new files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Some time ago I updated my app from Rails 1.2 to 2.3. The upgrade definitely worked (was in pagination hell for a while), and the app has been working fine.

But now I'm in the process of upgrading my app for mobile use and want to use the Mobile Fu plugin. However, that calls for changing the mime_types.rb file... and I don't have that. In fact, I don't have the entire Initializers folder in my config folder, nor the locales folder.

How do I get these directories into my app? Are there other things I'm missing? And what did I do wrong in the upgrade process?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run rake rails:upate?

Comment: yes I did. The answer below, however, specifies that the initializer & environment files are a convenience so aren't added by rails:update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running rake rails:update should have handled all the requirements of a Rails 2.3 app.  Initializers are not a requirement -- they are a new convenience that was added.  If you want the same default file structure as a new Rails 2.3 app, I recommend creating a dummy app and copying the initializer and environment files over so you're working with up-to-date templates.